# How to further subdivide a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples shown below.

```
[('29.886283', '-97.932083', '29.892553', '-97.921784'), ('29.890503', '-97.940304', '29.891903', '-97.938405'),...
```

Is there a way I can add additional subdivisions? so that my output would become:

```
[(('29.886283', '-97.932083'), ('29.892553', '-97.921784')), (('29.890503', '-97.940304'), ('29.891903', '-97.938405')),...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension.

```py
lst = [('29.886283', '-97.932083', '29.892553', '-97.921784'), ('29.890503', '-97.940304', '29.891903', '-97.938405')]
output = [(x[:2], x[2:]) for x in lst]
print(output) # print(output) # [(('29.886283', '-97.932083'), ('29.892553', '-97.921784')), (('29.890503', '-97.940304'), ('29.891903', '-97.938405'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension

```
[(tup[:2], tup[2:4]) for tup in l]

[(('29.886283', '-97.932083'), ('29.892553', '-97.921784')),
 (('29.890503', '-97.940304'), ('29.891903', '-97.938405'))]
```